# How to index a folder of epub, pdf documents with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have on my PC a folder containing many epub and pdf files that i want to be able to do fulltext search.

I know windows has already indexing service. but i would like to perform more logic than simple search for keywords.

So i would like to import those epub and pdf files into elasticsearch. anyone knows a script that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElasticSearch has implemented plugin for mapping attachments so hope this would help you:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/mapper-attachments.html
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments

It works fine for me.